# Nodejs pass log instance between modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I’ve logger which I initiate using a constractor in the `index.js` file.  Now I need
To pass the logger instance to other files, and I do it like this

**index.js**

```
const books = require(“./books”);

books(app, logger);
 
logger = initLogger({
  level: levels.error,
  label: “app”,
  version: "0.0.1",
});


app.listen(port, () => logger.info(`listening on port ${port}`));
```

And inside the `books.js` file I use it like following, get the logger from the `index.js` file and use it
inside the `books.js` file, **also pass it to another file with the function** `isbn.get(books, logger);`,
Is it recommended to do it like this? Is there a cleaner way in nodes ?

**books.js**

```
const isbn = require(“./isbn”);
module.exports = async function (app, logger) {

…
  try {
    Let books = await getBooks();
    logger.info(“get “books process has started”);
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error("Failed to fetch books", err);
    return;
  }

…

// this function is from the file “isbn” and I should pass the logger to it also
        try {

          let url = await isbn.get(books, logger);
        } catch (e) {
          res.send(e.message);
        }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating a module specifically for your logger configuration, then you can import that into your modules instead of using a side-effect of your business module to create a logger.

This will help if you ever need/want to change your logger configuration - instead of following a chain of business methods, you can just update the log configuration.

---

### Example

#### logger.js

```
'use strict';

// Any setup you need can be done here.
// e.g. load log libraries, templates etc.

const log = function(level, message) {
    return console.log(level + ": " + message);
};

module.exports = log;
```

#### business-logic.js

```
'use strict';

var log = require('./logger');
var stuff = require('./stuff');

const do_stuff = function (thing) {
    // do stuff here
    log("INFO", "Did stuff");
}
```

Comment: Sounds interesting, could you please provide an example ?

Comment: You can put the logger initialisation code that you have in index.js in a separate file called logger.js and then just export the instance, `module.exports = logger`.
You can then `require('./logger')` in other modules. Since node caches modules, you will get the same instance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty clean way of doing it, however it could be awkward when trying to share more variables or adding more requires. So, you could put all the variables in an object and destructure only the variables you need in `books.js`:

**index.js**:

```js
const state = {app, logger, some, other, variables};
require("./books")(state);
require("./another_file")(state);
```

**books.js**:

```js
module.exports = async function ({app, logger}) {

};
```